# Visual Studio Code icon Windows explorer

Tags: icons, default

I have a strange issue, i started today to use Visual Studio Code but every file is the default icon

[**Here** is every icon that VS can use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n42Ry.png)

[But all files take the default icon like **here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2qy6.png)

I can change the default Icon and it work but then it change **every** file extension.

How can I add the good Icon to the good file extension?
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, still an issue in 2024. You could use the FileTypesMan tool to edit the default icon per file type, however, it applies the same icon to all files associated with VSCode . For example, setting a different icon for php and js files, will use the same icon for both. So I just set the VSCode binary's icon to all, instead of the default one you mentioned.